# How do I make use of my exported firestore data?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, export, google-cloud-storage

Following [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#firebase-console) instructions for exporting firestore to google cloud storage I was able to produce an export folder in GCS.

After looking at the data it's kinda familiar I recognize parts of it. It's filled with stuff like this `zamount �* !ÆG·zT8@z` I recognize the word amount from one of my fields.

I don't understand how this export data is helpful or meaningful. If I needed to reconstitute my database from these file, how would I even start?

Clearly I'm missing something because this is borderline gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of a Firestore is undocumented.  It's a binary representation of the document data.  The only supported ways to import the data from that export is using the instructions in the related [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#import_data) using `gcloud firestore import` or the GCP console.

If you want an export whose format you can parse and work with programmatically, you should find a different mechanism.  I'm sure there are other libraries out there that can do what you want.